# ¿Qué significado tiene "cascabel" en "Yo te daré un cascabel / te lo prometo, mocita..."?

Tags: significado, sustantivos, letras-de-canciones, acepciones

Dice la canción de tuna *Clavelitos*:

> Yo te daré un cascabel
>   Te lo prometo, mocita
>   Si tú me das esa miel
>   Que llevas en la boquita

¿*Un cascabel* a cambio de un beso? ¿Hay otros significados de la palabra **cascabel**?

Comment: [Joselito - Clavelitos (English translation)](https://lyricstranslate.com/en/clavelitos-carnations.html). It seems that is literally a bell. Every transcript I have seen says "**el** cascabel" and not "**un** cascabel", but I don't think it matters much. I think that the meaning might be literal, even of doesn't make complete sense. It may be related to something cultural, rather than being a figure of speech. Maybe it's just because they needed a word to rhyme with "miel", "clavel" etc.

Comment: Es interesante ver que [_cascabel_](http://dle.rae.es/?w=cascabel) en el DLE tiene muchas expresiones relacionadas. Ninguna de ellas me suena, ni veo otras anteriores en el Mapa de diccionarios. Por lo que leo, la canción es de 1949, por lo que quién sabe si en esos tiempos había algún significado oculto que la censura española no viera...

Comment: Cascabel es una campanilla. Como puede llevar un gatito alredor de cuello.

Comment: En un diario de 1902 leo: "La familia Real estuvo luego en el Laberinto de 
los Cascabeles, recorriendo sus intrincados corredores, siéndole entregado á D. Alfonso un cascabel, 
que es el premio que se da á quien acierta la salida." Me pregunto si este concepto del cascabel como premio es el que se usa en la canción.

Comment: Es una canción tradicional de las tunas universitarias, cuyos miembros llevaban cascabeles cosidos en la ropa para que sonaran al compás de la musica. Cascabel rima con clavel, asi que es obvio el sentido literal de intercambiar un cascabel por un clavel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El contraste de *cascabel* y *clavel* aparece en una otra canción de Joselito:

> Doce cascabeles lleva mi caballo por la carretera
>   Y un par de claveles al pelo prendío lleva mi romera.
>
> - *Doce Cascabeles*, Joselito (1956)

Aquí parece tener plena interpretación literal.

---

**(advertencia: lo siguiente es pura especulación freudiana)**

No obstante, hay precedentes de canciones de la misma época (interpretadas por artistas jóvenes) que contienen ciertos 'eufemismos' (ej. [*Les sucettes*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_sucettes)).

Según este libro, hay una tradición de usar *cascabeles* como un eufemismo para los testículos en las canciones españolas y latinoamericanas:

> ... ahora, a intentar descifrar unos pocos de los símbolos eróticos, de las metáforas genitales, de los eufemismos mucho o poco velados, que afloran en la gran mayoría de estas cancioncillas...
>
> Es más que obvio que los *cascabelinos* y los *cascabelones* cuyo sospechoso
>   repiqueteo llena nuestra canción aluden eufemísticamente a los testículos
>   masculinos...
>
> Las siguientes cancioncillas terminarán de probar que el de los cascabeles es un tipo de eufemismo que cuenta con amplia tradición en puntos muy diversos de la geografía folclórica española e hispanoamericana, tal y como ya sugería la canción que comentamos...
>
> Si él [sic] del cascabel ha resultado ser un muy reconocible eufemismo genital masculino...
>
> - [*El lenguaje y sus máscaras: metáfora, tabú y eufemismo en una colección de cantos prohibidos asturianos*](https://www.academia.edu/26444549/El_lenguaje_y_sus_m%C3%A1scaras_met%C3%A1fora_tab%C3%BA_y_eufemismo_en_una_colecci%C3%B3n_de_cantos_prohibidos_asturianos), Jesús Suárez López, Fernando Ornosa Fernández

Por extensión, puede ser que aquí se use *cascabel*<sup>1</sup> para referirse al órgano sexual masculino generalmente, en contraste con la *boquita*/*clavel* que pueda tener una interpretación femenina:

> ... las referencias... a la boquita (32) (vagina):

> Sin embargo, la inseparable doble acepción del término clavel vuelve a tomar carta de naturaleza en esta ocasión, hasta el punto de convertirse en un vocablo sustituto de parte del cuerpo femenino que la decencia hace que pase por innominada...
>
> Así ocurre cuando al clavel, símbolo genésico femenino...
>
> - [*El retrato erótico femenino en el cancionero extremeño: 1. "son tus muslos dos columnas"*](http://www.cervantesvirtual.com/obra-visor/el-retrato-erotico-femenino-en-el-cancionero-extremeno-1-son-tus-muslos-dos-columnas/html/) , José María Dominguez Moreno (cervantesvirtual.com)

---

1. <sup>Si consideramos la transcripción de la letra más común «***el*** *cascabel*»</sup>

Comment: Con semejante eufemismo veo más lógico que diga "yo te daré el cascabel" que "un cascabel". :-D

Comment: Muy traído por los pelos...

Comment: Decian que "a veces un cigarro es sólo un cigarro"